# How can one send iOS push notifications from a Meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor, apple-push-notifications

I have failed to find a comprehensive tutorial for sending push notifications from a Meteor app. I understand that Meteor runs using node.js, so I have been following this highly referenced and recommended tutorial https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs but to no avail; upon deploying my app, it uploads but the website is then unresponsive (and given there are no errors with deployment, I cannot see where the problem lies, though I presume it has to do with how I'm organizing my files).

I have downloaded and loaded all of the certificates properly per the tutorial's instruction. I have used their example app to properly get my test device's ID. I just cannot figure out where to properly place additional files and dependencies given Meteor's folder configuration. How should it differ from the structure in the tutorial (in other words should this structure be placed inside of a folder within the `.meteor` folder of my app)?

I think the overarching issue is that Meteor simply structures their apps differently than plain Node.js apps, and as such I need to be placing these certificates and dependencies in a specific folder, not just the main application folder with `application.html`, `application.js`, and `application.css`.

Comment: You probably need to wrap `apnagent` into a new Meteor package. See https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-about-npm-node-modules

Comment: @GeoffreyBooth I completely agree, and after reading that document and following a relevant tutorial, I get an ``Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`` that I believe is referencing ``var apn = Meteor.require('apnagent');`` even though it's been downloaded as a dependency properly. Could this be the case?

Comment: Without seeing your code I have no idea, and I've never tried to set up APN myself; I was just pointing out how to work with NPM packages in Meteor in general. I would suggest you follow @alanning's answer as it appears he's actually gotten this to work :)

Comment: https://github.com/raix/push   Make sure you doublecheck your bundle identifier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We use the [apn](https://github.com/argon/node-apn) npm package with our Meteor app.  We looked at apnagent (because of that same tutorial) but went with apn due to its greater popularity.  Although apnagent should also work fine within your Meteor app, you may want to try apn just to troubleshoot.

We set it up server-side like this...

```
var apn = Meteor.require("apn"),
    path = Npm.require('path'),
    apnOptions = Meteor.settings.apnOptions || {},
    alertSound = apnOptions.sound || "alert.aiff",
    apnConnection

// default apn connection options
apnOptions = _.extend({
  cert: path.join(appRootPath, "private", "cert.pem"),
  key: path.join(appRootPath, "private", "key.pem"),
}, apnOptions)
apnConnection = new apn.Connection(apnOptions)
```

...and use it like this:

```
  sendAppleNotifications: function (alert, url, pushIds) {
    var note = new apn.Notification()

    // expires 1 hour from now
    note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600
    note.sound = alertSound
    note.alert = alert
    note.payload = {'url': url}

    _.each(pushIds, function (token) {
      var device = new apn.Device(token)
      apnConnection.pushNotification(note, device)
    })

    return {success:'ok'}
  },  // end sendAppleNotifications
```

Note that `Meteor.require` is enabled by the `npm` meteor package which you can read about [here](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html).  Alternately you could just put your code that uses the apn package in your own Meteor package and use `Npm.require` as [@GeoffreyBooth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223225/geoffrey-booth) suggested.

==

June 20, 2015 - Update

I recently answered a question about device tokens; hope these resources are helpful:

- [Token Generation and Dispersal, Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW12)
- [How to get a device token, see Step 10 in Sample IOS App section of article](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs)
- [Sending a Notification, apn library doc](https://github.com/argon/node-apn#sending-a-notification)

Comment: Excellent explenation. Thank you for providing such an in depth walk through

Comment: In this example, how do you obtain the `(alert, url, pushIds)` parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Cordova [`PushPlugin`](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), you will have to:

- roll your own integration with the Meteor `user` model, so that you can select which users to send your push notifications to.
- generate your own certificates,
- securely store the associated `.pem` and other authorization files.

In fact, it's quite a bit of work.

[`raix:push`](https://github.com/raix/push) "solves" the first issue, allowing a push notification to be delivered to a user or group of users. However:

- it's no longer maintained.
- it does not (in my experience) work anymore. iOs notifications show up but they don't vibrate the phone or make any sound. Some people have proposed hacks to get around it but none of them work for me.
- it asks you to version your production passwords and `.pem` files, which is certainly not considered safe practices for a proper 12-factor app.

[Pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/) is a service that makes it easy to send push notifications to your app, and includes automatic setup and handling of your `.pem` files and certificates and a super rich feature set.

[`lpender:meteor-pushwoosh`](https://github.com/lpender/meteor-pushwoosh) is a package I wrote, which

- Allows your app to create and receive push notifications.
- Allows querying by user when creating a notification.
- Works for iOs and Android devices.

Keep in mind, it's not totally clear from their [pricing](https://www.pushwoosh.com/pricing/) page, but after the free trial, it's $49 a month to continue use their API to programmatically generate messages from your app.

Comment: Whats up Lee!  It's niko.  Small world :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about iOS notifications, the apn package mentioned by alanning might do the job.

Meteor however has a package, [raix:push](https://atmospherejs.com/raix/push) that's far easier to use, and supports notifications on APN iOS, GCM Android, and partially on a few other systems (APN Safari web, GCM Chrome OS, Firefox OS).